# Dynamically change value in Formik when a state changes

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, formik, yup

I need to change the value in my form fields every time a state (called selectedProduct, its input field is not included in Formik tag) changes.
I tried:

1. putting the value I want in the initialValues (does not work obviously because at the first render I haven't choosen my selectedProduct yet)
2. putting the value I want in the "value" props in every field in formik.
   It almost work: Datepicker gets the right value, select box input does not get any value(idk why), text field take the right value but this is covered by the label. And that's because none of the fields get validated.

This is what I've done, with the two points above applied

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {
  Formik, Form, ErrorMessage, Field,
} from 'formik';
import {
  Button, TextField,
  MenuItem,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  startValidityDate: Yup.date().required(),
  discount: Yup.string().required(),
  days: Yup.string().required(),
});

const MyComponent = ({filteredProduct, daysList}) => {

   const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState('');

   const onChangeProduct = (product) => {
      setSelectedProduct(product.target.value);
   };

  const handleRunButton = (newExecution) => {
     console.log(newExecution);
  };

   return (
      <div>
          <div className={classes.productComboWrapper}>
             <div id="selectBoxNotIncludedInFormik">
                <TextField
                   margin="normal"
                   style={{}}
                   variant="outlined"
                   name="productId"
                   id="productId"
                   fullWidth
                   select
                   label="Select product"
                   value={selectedProduct?.id}
                   onChange={(product) => onChangeProduct(product)}
                >

                   <MenuItem key="" value="">
                      {StringsConst.noneSelected}
                   </MenuItem>
                   {filteredProduct?.map((el) => (
                      <MenuItem key={el} value={el}>
                         {el.isin}
                      </MenuItem>
                   ))}
               </TextField>
            </div>
         </div>

         <Formik
            initialValues={{
               startValidityDate: selectedProduct?.startValidityDate,
               days: selectedProduct?.coupon?.days,
               discount: selectedProduct?.discount,
            }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
               const newExecution = {
                  startValidityDate: values.startValidityDate,
                  days: values.days,
                  discount: values.discount,
               };
               handleRunButton(newExecution);
            }}
         >
            {({
               errors, dirty, setFieldValue, values,
            }) => (
               <Form>
                  <div className={classes.datePicker}>
                     <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                        <KeyboardDatePicker
                           disableToolbar
                           label="Start Validity Date"
                           inputVariant="outlined"
                           variant="inline"
                           autoOk
                           fullWidth
                           disabled
                           format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                           value={selectedProduct?.startValidityDate}
                           onChange={(dt) => setFieldValue('startValidityDate', dt)}
                           KeyboardButtonProps={{
                             'aria-label': 'change date',
                           }}
                       />
                   </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                 </div>

                 <div className={classes.fieldWrapper}>
                    <Field
                       className={classes.field}
                       name="discount"
                       as={TextField}
                       variant="outlined"
                       margin="normal"
                       fullWidth
                       id="discount"
                       autoComplete="discount"
                       placeholder="Discount"
                       disabled
                       value={selectedProduct?.discount}
                    />
                  </div>

                 <div className={classes.textFieldWrapper}>

                    <TextField
                        margin="normal"
                        style={{}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        name="days"
                        id="days"
                        fullWidth
                        select
                        label="Days"
                        disabled
                        value={selectedProduct?.coupon?.days}
                        onChange={(val) => setFieldValue('days', val.target.value)}
                    >

                       <MenuItem key="" value="">
                          {StringsConst.noneSelected}
                       </MenuItem>
                       {daysList.map((el) => (
                          <MenuItem key={el} value={el}>
                             {el}
                          </MenuItem>
                       ))}
                    </TextField>
           
                 </div>

                  <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
                     <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                     >
                         {StringsConst.Run}
                     </Button>
                  </div>
        
              </Form>
           )}
        </Formik>

      </div>
   )

}
```

So, the three input fields in the form are disabled, but I need them to fill when I choose a value in the first select box outside of the form.
Can you suggest me another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect input or button to the form outside the form.

like this code:

```
<form id="myForm">


<button> click me </button>
</form>


<input type="text" form="myForm"/>
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform